# Sticky header not working Angular5

Tags: css, angular, navigation

Hi guys having trouble with implemting a a sticky navbar in my Angular application.

This is my app component:

```
<div class="master-wrapper"> 
    <div class="master-container">
        <app-online-header></app-online-header>
            <div class="sticky">
                <app-navigation></app-navigation>     
            </div>
        <div class="background">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

My goal is to have the `<app-navigation>` component sticky. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

What I tried so far is in my `app-component` `CSS` file:

```
.sticky{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

### Question:

Why doesn't this make my `<app-navigation>` component sticky?

Comment: I have the very same problem. My sticky header won't scroll past the parent container. Even with overflow: visible and no height specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the class is defined in the `<div>` tag. The `class="sticky"` needs to be defined inside the `<nav>` or `<div>` tag that's placed inside the `<app-navigation>` component

Example:

HTML code:

```
<nav class="sticky">
  <ul class="menu">
    <!-- Insert client logo here -->
    <li class="css_logo">Monte</li>
    <!-- Insert your page navigation here -->
    <li class="css_link"><a [routerLink]="['Concept']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Concept</a></li>
    <li class="css_link"><a [routerLink]="['Fusion']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Fusion</a></li>
    <li class="css_link"><a [routerLink]="['Home']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS code:

```
.sticky {
  width: 100%;
  height:72px;
  margin:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Angular ts file

```
<!-- Common site Navigation bar -->
<app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
<!-- Application's Router sequence -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```